# Is there anyway to hide the gridlines between ticks and chartArea in ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, vue-chartjs

Is there anyway to remove this overflowing section of the gridlines?

[image]

This is exactly what I'm looking for:

[image]

I've seen a few post from years ago with this question and none of them have really yielded any results. Those were so long ago that I pray that a fix has happened since then.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `tickLength` to 0 in the grid options. To make the ticks still appear a bit away from the scale you can use the padding option:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        ticks: {
          padding: 4,
          crossAlign: 'far'
        },
        grid: {
          tickLength: 0
        }
      },
      x: {
        grid: {
          tickLength: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works amazing for the Y-axis. I am curious though about the x-axis. I need significantly higher padding for that to seem to work, but having a `crossAlign` value seems to have the inverse effect; bringing the ticks closer to the chart. 
I noticed you did put it in your example and I'm assuming it's exactly for that reason?

Thanks again!